# Axios ssl call HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, https, axios

I have install on VPS a nodejs server with react front.
I buy comondo SSL, fix both server and domain and after that if i call http it shows Mixted type error.
SSL checker gives A grade to SSL. I use https.create to create the node server. Also postman gives correct result for http://example.com/5000/posts.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com:5000/posts'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How i can fix this error ? Its axios , node or SSL problem ?

Answer (score 0):

in the first step, you have to know what's the mean by **Mixed Content**, quoted from [web.dev](https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/):

> Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS
> connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets,
> scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection. This is called
> mixed content because both HTTP and HTTPS content are being loaded to
> display the same page, and the initial request was secure over HTTPS.

to solve this problem, you must serve your API under SSL protocol.

Comment: Can i detect somehow those resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts)  ?

Comment: @tinizian mixed contents? yes u can, take a look into console (dev tool).